# Regex match everything from the last occurrence of either keyword

Tags: regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match everything from the last occurrence of either keyword (foo or bar) to the end of the string.

Example (a):

```
// I want to match ' foo do you?';
$source = 'This is foo and this is bar i like foo do you?';
$pattern = '/pattern/';
preg_match($pattern, $source, $matches);
```

I tried the following:

```
$pattern = '/( (foo|bar) .*)$/';
```

Thinking it would match the last occurrence of `foo` and all the following text, but it instead matches the first occurrence.

```
print_r($matches);

/*
Array
(
    [0] =>  foo and this is bar i like foo do you?
    [1] =>  foo and this is bar i like foo do you?
    [2] => foo
)
*/
```

**Note** I'm concerned with the theory and reasoning of how to do this, so please add some explanation or a link to to the relevant explanation, please.

Comment: I've used PHP in the example, but language is irrelevant. My only criteria is that the pattern is PCRE compliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.+((foo|bar).+)$
```

.+ matches many characters up front.

((foo|bar) matches and captures your keyword(s).

.+) matches and captures many characters.

$ matches the end of the string/line.

Using your example:

```
This is foo and this is bar i like foo do you?
                                   ^---------^
```

Comment: To clarify, removing `?:` will then add my keyword `(foo|bar)` to my match correct?

Comment: Also, is there a way to adapt this solution without matching the beginning of the string? i.e. `^.+`. In essence telling the Regex pattern matcher to evaluate my pattern from the end of the string?

Comment: I've removed the ?: for clarity as it's not needed. I updated the example too and also remove the "^" since it is likely not needed. This will match starting from the final "foo" or "bar" to the end of the string/line.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was looking for. Note, you comment does not accurately reflect your edit.

Comment: Glad it helps. How does it not reflect my comment? What'd I miss?

Comment: Code in answer `.+((?:foo|bar).+)$`. Comment: `I've removed the ?: for clarity as it's not needed.`. Also part of you're explanation still states `matches your keyword(s)but does not capture the keyword (change this if you want it to)`. Not really an issue for me, but will probably confuse anyone who stumbles across this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use a greedy match up front to consume as much of the haystack as you can before your pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> source = 'This is foo and this is bar i like foo do you?'
>>> pattern = '.*((?:foo|bar).*)'
>>> re.search(pattern, source).groups()[0]
'foo do you?'
```

A grottier way of doing it is to use negative look-aheads:

```
>>> # Negative look-ahead for the pattern: (?!.*(?:foo|bar))
>>> pattern = '((?:foo|bar)(?!.*(?:foo|bar)).*)'
>>> re.search(pattern, source).groups()[0]
'foo do you?'
```