# regex: how to include the first occurrence before the pattern?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

My text is:

```
120 something 130 somethingElse Paris
```

My goal is to capture `130 somethingElse Paris` which means only the last occurrence of number **BEFORE** `Paris`

I tried:

```
\d+.*Paris
```

But this captures the WHOLE string (from first occurrence of digit)

The rule is:

- Capture everything before `Paris` until first occurrence of digit is found.

Any clue ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/(\d+[^\d]*Paris)/gi
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/XDgxL/

Answer (score 1):

less tracebacks and without relying on greediness:

```
\d+[^0-9]*Paris
```

Answer (score 1):

for last occurrence

```
^code:[ ]([0-9a-f-]+)(?:(?!^code:[ ])[\s\S])*Paris
```

you have to customize with your text.

Please refer this:

[Regex match everything from the last occurrence of either keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440194/regex-match-everything-from-the-last-occurrence-of-either-keyword)

[Match from last occurrence using regex in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127282/match-from-last-occurrence-using-regex-in-perl)

[RegExp: Last occurence of pattern that occurs before another pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049622/regexp-last-occurence-of-pattern-that-occurs-before-another-pattern)

[Regex get last occurrence of the pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836145/regex-get-last-occurrence-of-the-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a ? after the * to make it un-greedy. Like this:

```
 \d+.*?Paris
```

Comment: be aware, that this solution is expensive on input string with a lot of numbers before the desired. As it needs a lot of tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
(\d+\D*?)+Paris
```

other occurences of the capturing group are overwritten by the last.

The lazy quantifier `*?` is used to force the pattern to stop at the first word "Paris". Otherwise, in a string with more than one word "Paris", the pattern will return the last group after the last word "Paris" with a greedy quantifier.